# Email is not sent

Tags: email, vbscript, qtp

I want to send an email from my vbscript code, the below code is working properly on my machine, but when I changed my machine, the code is no more able to send email.
There were no errors or problems occurred during run, but no emails were sent/delivered. 
Has anyone else faced a problem like this?

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

With objMessage
    .From = SendFrom
    .To   = SendTo
    .Subject  = "Subject"
    .Textbody = ""
    .HTMLBody = "<b>Body</b>"
    With .Configuration.Fields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")      = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")     = "SMTP.Gmail.Com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")   = "Username"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")   = "Password"
        .Update
    End With

    .Send
End With
```

Comment: Can you `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25` from the production machine? If not: what error do you get?

Comment: Doesn't this require both machines to have outlook installed?  Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Andrew: No, Outlook is not required.

Comment: Ansgar, I had tried telnet smtp of the company company and its work.
and the two devices have the outlook installed but with different versions ? does that may a cause  of problem ? 
but I had tried the code on other devices with no outlook and its work.

Comment: I tried to send email from above code but from different script from my machine that send email before, but unfortunately the email not sent, so I think its a script related issue, not to machine

Comment: cAnsgar, there are no errors, the problem just the email not sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you didn't post the entire code, check that your script doesn't contain a line

```
On Error Resume Next
```

If it does: remove the line and try again.

If you don't have that line in your script **and** the script doesn't raise an error **and** you can `telnet mailserver 25` then it's almost certain that the mail server accepted the mail for delivery and the problem is somewhere upstream. Check the mail server logs.

You can verify if the server actually accepts mail like this:

> `C:\>`**`telnet mailserver 25`**
>   `220 mailserver ESMTP`
>   **`HELO clientname`**
>   `250 mailserver`
>   **`MAIL FROM:<joe.average@example.com>`**
>   `250 2.1.0 Ok`
>   **`RCPT TO:<joe.average@example.com>`**
>   `250 2.1.5 Ok`
>   **`DATA`**
>   `354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>`
>   **`Subject: test`**
>   **`test`**
>   **`.`**
>   `250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4541E2227`
>   **`QUIT`**

The line before the `QUIT` command means that the server accepted the mail. The actual response text may vary depending on which MTA is used, but every MTA will respond with some line like that when it accepts a message.

Comment: thanks Ansgar, this were very helpful and solve the problem as found its related to "On Error Resume Next",

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine this is a permissions issue or a firewall issue if it is working on your machine but not the production machine. 
Carefully look at what is different, is one behind the firewall and other is not?

Comment: both machines are use same vpn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install CDonts library first. Search on microsoft.com for CDONTS library and install the same.

If you want to send without installation then try the second method. you have to initialize the objects.
In that example i remove h in the link because i can't post links

1. CDO.MESSAGE

   'Script to send an email through QTP nice one
   Set oMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

   '==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.
   '==Normally you will only change the server name or IP.
   oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

   'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
   oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") =""

   'Server port (typically 25)
   oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

   oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
   oMessage.Subject = "Test Mail"
   oMessage.Sender = ""
   oMessage.To =""
   'oMessage.CC = ""
   'oMessage.BCC = ""
   oMessage.TextBody = "Test Mail from QTP"&vbcrlf&"Regards,"&vbcrlf&"Test"
   oMessage.Send

   Set oMessage = Nothing